# A difficulty in understanding Theorem 4.3 in Israel Gohberg.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

This is the part of the proof that I could not understand in it why the writer wrote finally then $\langle z, v-w\rangle = 0.$

[image]

Could anyone explain this for me please?

Thanks!

Comment: You can let $r $ be as small as you want and therefore achieve that $2r >r^2 \cdot \lVert z\rVert ^2$. But then, the inequality can only hold if $<z, v-w>~=~~0$ and the claim follows.

Comment: your idea is not clear for me could you please write it in detail?@mxian

Comment: I think Wauzl's answer explains the idea behind my comment pretty well @Idonotknow. By just choosing $r$ small enough, we get a contradiction if $\langle z, v-w\rangle \neq 0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming $\langle z,v-w\rangle\neq0$, then from the last inequality, it follows by d9ividing both sides by $|\langle z,v-w\rangle|^2$
$$2r \leq r^2 \|z\|^2.$$
Since $r$ is arbitrary, let's assume $r> 0$ and divide by $2r$:
$$1 \leq \frac 12 r\|z\|^2.$$
If $z=0$, then we have the contradiction $1\leq 0$, so $\|z\|>0$. Let's now choose $r = \|z\|^{-2}$. Then we get
$$ 1\leq \frac 12 \|z\|^{-2}\|z\|^2 = \frac12, $$
which is a contradiction. So our initial assumption must not hold, so $\langle z,v-w\rangle=0$.

Comment: can not we say that $|| z ||$ is constant, but $r$ is variable so by changing the value of $r$ we can change the value of $z$ which is a contradiction?

Comment: You could, but usually it is phrased like that: $\|z\|$ is constant, but $r$ may be chosen so small, such that $\frac 2r \leq  \|z\|^2$ is violated, which is a contradiction.